# Python: Create Pandas Dataframe based on Value of Variables Assigned Values Earlier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following variables.  The values associated with variables will change so I want to keep this dynamic.

```
int = 3
hours = 2
cost = 20
```

Now I want to create a pandas data frame that takes in those dynamic variables.  Below is the code I tried:

```
d = {'F':737, 'INT':[int], 'LH':[hours], 'COST':[cost]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Below is the error I get:

> NameError: name 'interval' is not defined

This is my desired table:

```
F     INT  LH     COST
737   3    2      20
```

Comment: Your code works just fine. You probably have a typo in your `d` (probably wrote `interval` instead of `int` which is the name of your variable). Also, `int` is not a good name for a variable because it's a built in type

Comment: you are right!  the code does work

Comment: I would say don't use `int` as variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `int` is not a good name for a variable as it is a keyword. Next, do you want your values to be lists/arrays? when you do `'LH':[hours]` it means that the value of the key `LH` is an array/list with a single item, which is `hours` in this case. unless you want this behavior, you should write something like

```
num = 3
hours = 2
cost = 20
d = {'F':737, 'INT':num, 'LH':hours, 'COST':cost}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```